# Implementing a favorites features on MoviesApp

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-room

I'm currently writing an android app in Kotlin that displays a list of movies and I want to add a favorites feature. I have added a checkbox in the recyclerview attached to each movie where by clicking on the checkbox, the movie is added to the favorites.

However, I'm having trouble implementing the right functions in the recyclerview adapter. I don't know how to get a reference to the movie which holds the checked checkbox to pass it into the method that adds it to the recycler view.

Appreciate all the help I can get.

Below you'll find the relevant code.

MoviesListViewModel.kt

```
package com.example.moviesapp

import androidx.lifecycle.*
import androidx.paging.cachedIn
import com.example.moviesapp.network.MovieDao
import com.example.moviesapp.network.MoviesRepository
import com.example.moviesapp.network.MoviesResults
import dagger.hilt.android.lifecycle.HiltViewModel
import javax.inject.Inject

const val DEFAULT_QUERY = " "


@HiltViewModel
class MoviesListViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: MoviesRepository,
    private val movieDao: MovieDao,
): ViewModel() {


    private var currentQuery = MutableLiveData(DEFAULT_QUERY)

    val moviesTrending = repository.getTrendingMovies().cachedIn(viewModelScope)

    val moviesAction = repository.getActionMovies().cachedIn(viewModelScope)

    val moviesComedy = repository.getComedyMovies().cachedIn(viewModelScope)

    val moviesHorror = repository.getHorrorMovies().cachedIn(viewModelScope)

    val moviesRomance = repository.getRomanceMovies().cachedIn(viewModelScope)

    val moviesScifi = repository.getScifiMovies().cachedIn(viewModelScope)




    suspend fun favoriteMovies(movie: MoviesResults.Movies) {
        movieDao.favorite(movie)
    }
    suspend fun deleteMovies(movie: MoviesResults.Movies) {
        movieDao.delete(movie)
    }



    val movies = currentQuery.switchMap {queryString ->
        repository.getSearchResults(queryString).cachedIn(viewModelScope)

    }




    fun searchMovies(query: String) {

    currentQuery.value = query

    }

    class MoviesListViewModelFactory(private val repository: MoviesRepository, private val movieDao: MovieDao): ViewModelProvider.Factory {
        override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
            if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(MoviesListViewModel::class.java)) {
                @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
                return MoviesListViewModel(repository, movieDao) as T
            }
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class")

        }


    }



}
```

MoviesListAdapter.kt

```
package com.example.moviesapp

import android.util.SparseBooleanArray
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.paging.PagingDataAdapter
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DiffUtil
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import com.example.moviesapp.databinding.MovieLayoutBinding
import com.example.moviesapp.network.MoviesRepository
import com.example.moviesapp.network.MoviesResults

val IMAGE_BASE_URL = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500"

class MoviesListAdapter constructor(private val listener: OnItemClickListener, private val repository: MoviesRepository) :
    PagingDataAdapter<MoviesResults.Movies, MoviesListAdapter.MoviesListViewHolder>(
        MOVIE_COMPARATOR
    ) {








    var checkBoxStateArray = SparseBooleanArray()



    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MoviesListViewHolder {
        val binding = MovieLayoutBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)


        return MoviesListViewHolder(binding)
    }


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MoviesListViewHolder, position: Int) {


        if(!checkBoxStateArray.get(position,false))
        {//checkbox unchecked.
            holder.checkbox.isChecked = false


        }
        else
        {//checkbox checked
            holder.checkbox.isChecked = true
        }

        val currentItem = getItem(position)
        if (currentItem != null) {
            holder.bind(currentItem)
        }

    }


    inner class MoviesListViewHolder(private val binding: MovieLayoutBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {




        private fun showToast(string: String) {
            Toast.makeText(itemView.context, string, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        }

        var checkbox = binding.favoritesCheckbox

        init {
            binding.root.setOnClickListener {
                val position = bindingAdapterPosition
                if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                    val item = getItem(position)
                    if (item != null)
                        listener.onItemClick(item)
                }
            }
        }


        init {
            checkbox.setOnClickListener {

                if (checkbox.isChecked) {
                    showToast("Movie added to favorites")




                } else {
                    showToast("Movie removed from favorites")

                }

            }


        }


        fun bind(movie: MoviesResults.Movies) {
            binding.apply {
                movieTitle.text = movie.title
                movieRating.text = movie.vote_average
                movieYear.text = movie.release_date
                Glide.with(itemView)
                    .load(IMAGE_BASE_URL + movie.poster_path)
                    .centerCrop()
                    .error(R.drawable.ic_baseline_error_outline_24)
                    .into(movieImage)

            }
        }



    }


    interface OnItemClickListener {
        fun onItemClick(movie: MoviesResults.Movies)
    }


    companion object {
        private val MOVIE_COMPARATOR = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<MoviesResults.Movies>() {
            override fun areItemsTheSame(
                oldItem: MoviesResults.Movies,
                newItem: MoviesResults.Movies
            ) =
                oldItem.id == newItem.id


            override fun areContentsTheSame(
                oldItem: MoviesResults.Movies,
                newItem: MoviesResults.Movies
            ) =
                oldItem == newItem


        }

    }


}
```

MoviesRepository.kt

```
package com.example.moviesapp.network

import androidx.paging.Pager
import androidx.paging.PagingConfig
import androidx.paging.liveData
import javax.inject.Inject
import javax.inject.Singleton


@Singleton
//We use Inject because I own this class, unlike the Retrofit and MoviesApi class
class MoviesRepository @Inject constructor(private val moviesApi: MoviesApi, private val movieDao: MovieDao) {
    //This function will be called later on in the ViewModel
fun getSearchResults(query: String) =
    Pager(
        config = PagingConfig(
            pageSize = 20,
            //Value at which we want to start dropping items
            maxSize = 100,
            //Disabling placeholders for objects that haven't been loaded yet
            enablePlaceholders = false
        ),
        pagingSourceFactory = {MoviesPagingSource(moviesApi, query)}
    //Turn this pager into a stream of paging data to get live updates
    ).liveData

    fun getTrendingMovies() =
        Pager(
            config = PagingConfig(
                pageSize = 20,
                //Value at which we want to start dropping items
                maxSize = 100,
                //Disabling placeholders for objects that haven't been loaded yet
                enablePlaceholders = false
            ),
            pagingSourceFactory = {MoviesTrendingPagingSource(moviesApi)}
            //Turn this pager into a stream of paging data to get live updates
        ).liveData

    fun getActionMovies() =
        Pager(
            config = PagingConfig(
                pageSize = 20,
                //Value at which we want to start dropping items
                maxSize = 100,
                //Disabling placeholders for objects that haven't been loaded yet
                enablePlaceholders = false
            ),
            pagingSourceFactory = {MoviesActionPagingSource(moviesApi)}
            //Turn this pager into a stream of paging data to get live updates
        ).liveData

    fun getComedyMovies() =
        Pager(
            config = PagingConfig(
                pageSize = 20,
                //Value at which we want to start dropping items
                maxSize = 100,
                //Disabling placeholders for objects that haven't been loaded yet
                enablePlaceholders = false
            ),
            pagingSourceFactory = {MoviesComedyPagingSource(moviesApi)}
            //Turn this pager into a stream of paging data to get live updates
        ).liveData

    fun getHorrorMovies() =
        Pager(
            config = PagingConfig(
                pageSize = 20,
                //Value at which we want to start dropping items
                maxSize = 100,
                //Disabling placeholders for objects that haven't been loaded yet
                enablePlaceholders = false
            ),
            pagingSourceFactory = {MoviesHorrorPagingSource(moviesApi)}
            //Turn this pager into a stream of paging data to get live updates
        ).liveData

    fun getRomanceMovies() =
        Pager(
            config = PagingConfig(
                pageSize = 20,
                //Value at which we want to start dropping items
                maxSize = 100,
                //Disabling placeholders for objects that haven't been loaded yet
                enablePlaceholders = false
            ),
            pagingSourceFactory = {MoviesRomancePagingSource(moviesApi)}
            //Turn this pager into a stream of paging data to get live updates
        ).liveData

    fun getScifiMovies() =
        Pager(
            config = PagingConfig(
                pageSize = 20,
                //Value at which we want to start dropping items
                maxSize = 100,
                //Disabling placeholders for objects that haven't been loaded yet
                enablePlaceholders = false
            ),
            pagingSourceFactory = {MoviesScifiPagingSource(moviesApi)}
            //Turn this pager into a stream of paging data to get live updates
        ).liveData


      suspend fun addToFavorites(movies: MoviesResults.Movies) {
          movieDao.favorite(movies)

      }

    suspend fun removeFromFavorites(movies: MoviesResults.Movies) {
        movieDao.delete(movies)

    }








}
```

MovieDao.kt

```
package com.example.moviesapp.network

import androidx.room.Dao
import androidx.room.Delete
import androidx.room.Insert
import androidx.room.OnConflictStrategy


@Dao
interface MovieDao {


    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun favorite(movie: MoviesResults.Movies)


    @Delete
    suspend fun delete(movie: MoviesResults.Movies)



}
```

MoviesRoomDatabase.kt

```
package com.example.moviesapp.network

import android.content.Context
import androidx.room.Database
import androidx.room.Room
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase


@Database(entities = [MoviesResults.Movies::class], version = 1, exportSchema=false)
abstract class MoviesRoomDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

abstract fun movieDao(): MovieDao


//INSTANCE will keep a reference to the database. This helps in mainting one instance of the database opened since it is an expensive resource to create and maintain
companion object {


    //Volatile variable will never be cached
    //Makes sure INSTANCE is always up-to-date and same for all execution threads
    //Changes made by one thread to INSTANCE are visible to all other threads imemdiately

    @Volatile
private var INSTANCE: MoviesRoomDatabase? = null
    fun getDatabase(context: Context): MoviesRoomDatabase {

        //Wrapping code to get database inside synchronized block means that only one thread of execution can enter this block of code, making sure database is initialized only once
        return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
         val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
             context.applicationContext,
             MoviesRoomDatabase::class.java,
         "Movies_Database"
         )
             .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
             .build()
            INSTANCE = instance

            return instance
        }

    }



}
```

Movies.kt

```
package com.example.moviesapp.network

import android.os.Parcelable
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey
import com.squareup.moshi.Json
import kotlinx.parcelize.Parcelize

@Parcelize
@Entity
data class MoviesResults(
    @Json(name="results") val results: Movies,
): Parcelable {
    @Parcelize
    @Entity
    data class Movies(
    @Json(name= "title") val title: String,
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @Json(name="id") val id: Int,
    @Json(name="release_date") val release_date: String ,
    @Json(name="overview") val overview: String ,
    @Json(name="vote_average") val vote_average: String,
    @Json(name="poster_path") val poster_path: String,
    @Json(name="original_language") val original_language: String,
    ): Parcelable {

}
}
```

MoviesApplication.kt

```
package com.example.moviesapp

import android.app.Application
import com.example.moviesapp.network.MoviesRoomDatabase
import dagger.hilt.android.HiltAndroidApp


@HiltAndroidApp
class MoviesApplication: Application() {
    val database : MoviesRoomDatabase by lazy {MoviesRoomDatabase.getDatabase(this)}

}
```

Comment: Do you mean that how to get that movie object which has been checked by clicking the checkbox in the item of  recyclerview?

Comment: I don't know what to pass to the method that I'm gonna call in the onclicklistener in the adapter to put the movie in the favorites

Comment: what's the method you gonna call? Kindly mention it with its parameters.

Comment: Addtofavorites and removetofavorites in the repository

Comment: you have list of movie from network and you wanna check the box and add that movie into other list? which you made for favorite movies

Comment: Yes that's exactly the case

Comment: ok and what is this repository reference in the adapter?

Comment: Probably forgot it, but when I use the method in the repo what do I pass to it? How do I get a reference to the movie that holds the checked checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use a Listner which registers your clicks like [here](https://github.com/sarafanshul/Habbit/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/projectdelta/habbit/ui/adapter/RecyclerItemClickListenr.kt) , [example](https://github.com/sarafanshul/Habbit/blob/eac5d25ae8aadb261052a6b69c3242ad227b645c/app/src/main/java/com/projectdelta/habbit/ui/fragment/TodoFragment.kt#L116)
2. In your data class `Movies.kt` you can add a variable which shows if a movie is favorite i.e

```
var isFavourite : Boolean = false
```

and you can query on based of this column when needed.

Comment: But there's still the issue how do I use the method in the adapter if I use the boolean variable

Comment: easiest way is to use select movie a movie ( ex : by long press , override the function in listner by implementing your `fun onItemClick(movie: MoviesResults.Movies)`) and then using alert dialog  asking if you want to star this movie , if yes then set the boolean to true and update database.

Comment: It's not possible to do via the checkbox?

Comment: It is possible but then you need to have two states in your activity 1) View State , 2) Edit State which can be toggled by an action , then in Edit state you have to Implement the checkbox feature and its operation . This all will need large implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Utilize the kotlin's feature, you can use lambda in the adapter for the callbacks:

```
class Adapter(
    private val onAddToFavorite: (Movie) -> Unit
) {
    
    inner class MovieViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root){

        fun bind(movie: Movie) {

            if (checkBox.isChecked) {
                onAddToFavorite(movie)
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Now, in your view(activity/ fragment) you will be having callback for the specific movie and then add into favorite, like this:

```
 Adapter{
          movie ->
        viewmodel.addFavorite(movie)
    }
```

Comment: By the view you mean the viewholder?

Comment: Updated the answer. No, view mean activity/fragment.

Comment: The function in the viewmodel is a suspend function though it's not working

Comment: use viewmodelScope in your ``viewmodel`` and update question how you are doing with lambda.

Comment: But then I'll have to update the adapter in every fragment. Is there no way to call a function in the adapter from the viewmodel or repository?